# Is it not possible to use a function in an insert statement in ole db command in ssis?

Tags: insert, ssis, oledbcommand

i am using an **insert** statement as below in an OLE DB Command in data flow task of SSIS:

```
insert into abc (dtlastmodified)
values ( dateadd(minute, datepart(TZoffset, sysdatetimeoffset()), ?)
```

and i need to map '?' to LastChangedDatetime which is an input to the OLE DB Command.

But i am getting an error :
**"Insert value List does not Match Column List"**

Also, the same thing works fine when using an update :

```
update abc set dtlastmodified=dateadd(minute, datepart(TZoffset, sysdatetimeoffset()), ?)
```

Kindly help me out with the insert statement as to why it is not accepting the dateadd function.

Comment: the insert statement is :

insert into abc (dtlastmodified) values ( dateadd(minute, datepart(TZoffset, sysdatetimeoffset()), ?))

Answer (score 0):

You are missing bracket probably?

```
insert into abc (dtlastmodified)
values (
  dateadd(
    minute, datepart(TZoffset, sysdatetimeoffset()),
    ?
  )
)
```